# Selectize reduces width of dropdown making options illegible

Tags: selectize.js

When loading selectize selects inside a table, the table automatically reduces the cell width to the miminum size possible squeezing selectize dropdowns. When you open dropdown, the options are illegible - the first 3-4 characters can be read and the rest are hidden.

Here is a sample fiddle:

```
$(function() {
    $('select').selectize({    plugins: ['remove_button']
});

          <form role="form" id="contacts">

            <table>
            <tr><td>  <select placeholder="Select a person..." multiple>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
                <option value="17">John Doe</option>
                <option value="19">John Donut</option>
                <option value="21">Dante Joe</option>
                <option value="22">Jo Dod</option>
                <option value="1">Nikola</option>
                <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
                <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
              </select></td>
              <td>  <select placeholder="Select a person..." multiple>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
                <option value="17">John Doe</option>
                <option value="19">John Donut</option>
                <option value="21">Dante Joe</option>
                <option value="22">Jo Dod</option>
                <option value="1">Nikola</option>
                <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
                <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
              </select></td>
              <td>  <select placeholder="Select a person..." multiple>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
                <option value="17">John Doe</option>
                <option value="19">John Donut</option>
                <option value="21">Dante Joe</option>
                <option value="22">Jo Dod</option>
                <option value="1">Nikola</option>
                <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
                <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
              </select></td>
              <td>  <select placeholder="Select a person..." multiple>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
                <option value="17">John Doe</option>
                <option value="19">John Donut</option>
                <option value="21">Dante Joe</option>
                <option value="22">Jo Dod</option>
                <option value="1">Nikola</option>
                <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
                <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
              </select></td> <td>  <select placeholder="Select a person..." multiple>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
                <option value="17">John Doe</option>
                <option value="19">John Donut</option>
                <option value="21">Dante Joe</option>
                <option value="22">Jo Dod</option>
                <option value="1">Nikola</option>
                <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
                <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
              </select></td> <td>  <select placeholder="Select a person..." multiple>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
                <option value="17">John Doe</option>
                <option value="19">John Donut</option>
                <option value="21">Dante Joe</option>
                <option value="22">Jo Dod</option>
                <option value="1">Nikola</option>
                <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
                <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
              </select></td> <td>  <select placeholder="Select a person..." multiple>
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>
                <option value="17">John Doe</option>
                <option value="19">John Donut</option>
                <option value="21">Dante Joe</option>
                <option value="22">Jo Dod</option>
                <option value="1">Nikola</option>
                <option value="3">Nikola Tesla</option>
                <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
              </select></td></tr>
            </table>
             

          </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/csjqaf3m/

As you can see, the items in the list are completely illegible.

My columns cannot have fixed widths because the data loaded into them varies - in one instance, I could have 3 options with max 6 characters, next could load in data with up 15 characters width ...

Not overly concerned about the width of the dropdown BUT when it is open, I expect the select to show all data and make sure it can be read and is visible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping there was an option or method that existed to make this work but apparently not so I designed a solution which isn't perfect but it's as close as I think I'm going to get.

When creating the dropdown I use jQuery to test the length of every item in the dropdown and store the largest length. I then pad out the default select option with dashes so that the length matches the largest element:

```
var optionLength = 0;

this
.data()
.sort()
.unique()
.each( function(d) {
    // Get the length of the longest 
    optionLength = (d.length>optionLength?d.length:optionLength);
    select.append($('<option>' + d + '</option>'));
} );

var spacer = "-".repeat(optionLength/2);
select.prepend('<option value="">'+spacer+' All '+spacer+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a min-width for dropdown

```
.selectize-dropdown{
  min-width:250px !important;  
}
```

Comment: That makes it a fixed width. I am trying to avoid using a fixed width due to the dyanmic nature of the content